# How to write test to file system in kotlin multi platform

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

how to write text to file system in kotlin multi platform(into android & iOS). If not possible and we have to use expect/actual approach, then any example will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of libraries for this task, very popular is [Okio](https://square.github.io/okio/).